# Bound A buttoncell to an image link in DatagridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

i have a gridview that load column with code via method of class and code id :

```
            Queue objQueue = new Queue();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = objQueue.GetAllQueue();
            DataGridViewButtonColumn btnFile = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
            btnFile.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
            btnFile.Name = "btnViewFile";
            btnFile.Text = "View";
            btnFile.HeaderText = "View Image";
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(btnFile);
```

Botton load in data grid view with no problem but how can i bind this button to open image link via new designed form or windows image and fax viewer .

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
btnFile.Click += btnFile_Click;
```

now define the btnFile_Click file to stream the image in Response

Answer (score 0):

solution :

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex ==1) //Assuming the button column as second column, if not can change the index
            {
                //check if anything needs to be validated here
                Form1 f = new Form1();
                f.navId = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                f.Show();

            }
        }
```

In the above code, assign the value of the id from using this statement
f.navId = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();

For this to work, just declare a public variable in the target form (navId in this eg)

Answer (score 0):

You can attach an event handler to the DataGrid view as

```
dataGridView1.CellClick += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellClick);
```

and handle it as

```
void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 0) //Or your Button Index location
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Here");
            }
        }
```

Then you can create a new form and show it or open an image link as you want it to do.